# How to validate phone number using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, request

how to validate virtual number/phone number in java?

Virtual number can be 12 characters long and format should be 90507167819. I want to check for length and alphanumeric character.
virtualNumber is string and example : 905523458295

Comment: What do you want to validate about it?

Comment: which country? with or without access code, hyphenated etc....? Write a custom validator..

Comment: for Turkey. The virtual number can be 12 characters long and I want to do a validation that also returns false when I enter a value like 9050716781AB.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit vague but I will cover various aspects of a phone number validation

The first level of validation is a simple phone number **format** validation. This can be performed by a regular expression match.

```
String pattern = "\\d{10}|(?:\\d{3}-){2}\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-?\\d{4}";
if (inputString.matches(pattern)) {     
    System.out.println("Valid"); 
} else {     
    System.out.println("Invalid"); 
}
```

refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104546/java-regular-expressions-to-validate-phone-numbers) for more on regular expression matching.

Next is a **locale** based validation of the number based on country code, starting digits and number of digits as well as various formatting styles for numbers. The best solution for this is to use Google PhoneUtils. They do an excellent job of keeping up with the ever changing number formats in various countries/regions.
Import the google phone utils library with maven or gradle into your project.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
    <version>8.12.45</version>
</dependency>
```

Usage as below

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

More details about the project [here](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber)

Finally, the last method of a phone number validation is to actually place an **call** to the number. This requires a more elaborate integration with a VoIP automation provider such as Twilio.
Twilio provides APIs for phone validation. You can call these APIs from your java code and pass a phone number and handle the various response codes. More details here. This is a paid solution
https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/tutorials/validation-and-formatting

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom validator to accommodate your phone number rules, refer to this article where you can learn how to create custom validators https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator.

You can use regex also to make sure the input matches what you expect.